Generalized Langlands correspondence for non-simply connected groups
Consider a connected real reductive group $G$ and its complexification $G_{\mathbb{C}}$. Define the notions of a generalized Langlands dual group $G^\vee$ for non-simply connected groups, denoting the fundamental group of $G$ by $\pi_1(G)$.
I am interested in the characterization of the category of perverse sheaves on the affine Grassmannian $Gr = G_{\mathbb{C}}(K)/G_{\mathbb{C}}(O)$ and its dual $Gr^\vee = G^\vee(K)/G^\vee(O)$.
In particular, what are the conditions under which an equivalence of categories
$$ D^{\text{perv}}(Gr) \simeq D^{\text{perv}}(Gr^\vee) $$
holds? Does the monodromy representation associated with the moduli stack of $G$-bundles play some type of role?
My first thoughts are to see how the structure of $\pi_1(G)$ impacts the derived category's equivalence class.

EQUIVARIANT perverse sheaves on the affine Grassmannian are equivalent to the representation category of the Langlands dual group, so the most generous interpretation I can make of this question is "when is $G \simeq \hat{G}$"? This can be answered by hand.
